# how do I show all the selected options in the text field

Tags: javascript, selected

how do I get my javascript to show more than one selected in de text field I am planning on adding way more 's so I don't want to make a insane long array

```js
function myFunction() {
    var skilllist = document.getElementById("skilllist");
    console.log(skilllist.selectedIndex);
    document.getElementById("skillfield").value = skilllist.options[skilllist.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
   


  <form>
Select your favorite browser:
 <select name="skillist[]" id="skilllist"  multiple>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
    <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>  
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
    <option value="Wordpress">wordpress</option>
 </select>
<p>jouw skills zijn: <input type="text" id="skillfield" size="50"></p>
</form>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding an event handler on `blur` event to the select element.
With such an approach you are able to select one or more list items and dynamically render their text content.

```
document.getElementById("skilllist").addEventListener('blur', function(e){

   var options = e.target.options,
       selected_content = "";

   for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
       if (options[i].selected) selected_content += options[i].textContent + ", ";
   }    

   document.getElementById("skillfield").value = selected_content;

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLyw7vhd/

> For mobile devices : try to replace event name `'blur'` to `'focusout'`
>   (or `'change'`) in `addEventListener` function

Comment: is it possible to do it in realtime so you don't have to click the textfield?

Comment: in the above approach, you don't have " to click the textfield", you just need to "focus out" from the selectbox, that action will indicate that you have changed(selected) something in selectbox

Comment: im trying to get it working on mobile aswel but you need to tap the screen again to change to focus do you know a way how to change that?

Comment: @RemcoHorters, for mobile devices : try to replace event name `'blur'` to `'focusout'` (or `'change'`) in `addEventListener` function

Comment: @RemcoHorters, thanks, I've added my last advice to the answer's content